# when the option button click textfield text should be erased not disable

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, collapsable

I have [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N1IuHWv0vNmphuEdNWWG?p=preview). When the provided script option is enabled, the textbox in text should be erased.

- Click Plus button in the Plnkr
- Go to collapse panel inside radio button is there. Click provided script button.

Relevant code:

```
<table class="range-table" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index">
        <td>
          <accordion>
            <accordion-group is-open="status.open" ng-repeat="group in groups">
              <accordion-heading>
                <span ng-click="opened(group, $index)">{{group.title}}{{contact}}</span><i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
              </accordion-heading>
              <div> {{group.content}}
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" value="custom" required /> Customize</label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program " value="other" required ng-click="form.OtherProgram = null" /> Provide Script</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="form.OtherProgram" ng-disabled="form.Program != 'other'" name="Program_Other" ng-required="form.Program != 'other'" />
              </div>
            </accordion-group>
          </accordion>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `ng-click` to change the `ng-model` text input to `null`:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program " value="other" required ng-click="form.OtherProgram = null" />
```

EDIT:

If I understood here is an updated answer, use a custom variable `disableOption` set to false initially, then play with that with `ng-click` and you are done:

```
<label ng-init="disableOption = false">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" value="custom" ng-click="disableOption = true"  required /> Customize
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program " value="other" ng-click="disableOption = false" required /> Provide Script
</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="form.OtherProgram" ng-disabled="disableOption === true" name="Program_Other" ng-required="form.Program != 'other'" />
```

Comment: When click on "Customize" textfield should disabled(including text).Again When click on "Customize" option textfied should be clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear what you are asking. Customize it's not an input it's a radio and I can't understand your needs.

Comment: When click on "Customize" option textfield should disabled including textbox value

Comment: click on "provide script" option enter some text in textfield.now click on "Customize" option now u can see textfield disabled right.. I need the textfield text too disable.(which u entered some text know).

Comment: I updated the answer, now if you choose customize radio the input becomes disabled, intstead if you click the option radio it re-enables the text input